# Gratis text to speech Windows app which does not need training

Tags: windows, gratis, speech-recognition

I am trying to follow a video tutorial which is simply too fast. I have to pause every 5 seconds to try ot take notes.

Is there a gratis text to speech Windows app which does not need training?

Comment: Text-to-speech usually doesn't need training; it is speech-to-text/speech transcription that does, and it sounds like that's what you're looking for. I've never encountered or heard of any speech transcription app that didn't require training.

Comment: You could also have a look into players which can change the playback speed. Typically the pitch would get lower, but some of them have correction for that. Some typists have a foot pedal for pause/resume on voice recordings so they keep their hands free.

Comment: Thomas, thanks, but can you recommend one?